# Install packages (pywin32, win10toast and many others) via pip install not possible

Tags: python, pip, pywin32, python-3.8

I have installed python 3.8, and need to install pywin (pywin32)

However, pip cannot find it. Note, i have tried to install some other packages with pip install command in terminal before, but those don't work either.

A few possibly relevant data points:

- new install of python 3.8.1
- windows 10 x64
- python 3.7 was previously installed on the machine
- I'm using pycharm 2019.3.3. There in venv/Lib/site-packages it shows that setuptools and pip is installed.
- I use the terminal in pycharm, since however it's the only console which let's me go to the path system C: ---> the normal cmd of windows is always on M:, even if I change directory, it always goes back to M: (I don't know why)....

What I tried:

```
*cmd -> netsh winhttp show proxy  #As I thought the installation problems might relate to the proxy. But it doesn't because at work we don't use one, it's DirectAccess (no proxy).

*to install pywin32; Errorcode:
    Collecting pywin32
          Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object
        at 0x000002189212F3A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pywin32/
          Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object
        at 0x000002189212FE20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pywin32/
          Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object
        at 0x0000021892150880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pywin32/
          Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object
        at 0x0000021892150AC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pywin32/
          Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object
        at 0x00000218921507C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pywin32/
          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )
        No matching distribution found for pywin32

*to install pypiwin32; Errorcode:   
    Collecting pypiwin32
          Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object
        at 0x000002670BE9FFA0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pypiwin32/
          Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object
        at 0x000002670BE9FCD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pypiwin32/
          Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object
        at 0x000002670BEC08B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pypiwin32/
          Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object
        at 0x000002670BEC0AF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pypiwin32/
          Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object
        at 0x000002670BEC07F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pypiwin32/
          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pypiwin32 (from versions: )
        No matching distribution found for pypiwin32
```

Can you help me please? 
Also, if there is already one topic which is helpful, I would be happy about it. I wasted hours of searching this website, but there's too much...

How did I get to this issue:
I want to write a code with popup notification for the Windows taskbar. Therefore want to use win10toast but pip cannot install - I checked the requirements and it's necessary to install pywin32 and setuptools first. So setuptools was pre-installed, therefore ok. 
But pywin32 installation is not possible. 
If you could offer me a better solution than win10toast this would also be helpful ;-)

A million thanks! Wish you a happy day :)

Comment: Does `pip install pywin32` work if you jsut try to run it from your `cmd` with no venv?

Comment: How can I run it w/o venv? @FlyingTeller

Comment: just open a `cmd` and type the command (assuming you have added python to PATH)

Comment: Yes I've tried this a lot of times...same error:

  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002D34A8547C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pywin32/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32

Comment: I'm clueless... :(

Comment: Is all the code and your python installation also on the `M` drive? I am assuming it is a network drive?

Comment: The problem with the M: drive I fixed yesterday evening. I just had to disconnect the M: drive and then the console started as usual on C: 
Python I have installed on C:

Might it be a proxy problem?

Comment: You said that `python 3.7 was previously installed on the machine` - did you ever have any problem with that version?

Comment: I didn't use it much. So never tried to install via pip...

Answer (score -1):

You could use plyer instead of win10toast just install it And write

```
From plyer import notification
a= Notification.notify(title= ,message=,icon=,time=)
```